# How to get sequence of items from list in Qore

Tags: qore

Is there a Qore operator/function to get sublist from a list without modifying source list, i.e. equivalent of `substr()`. `extract` operator removes items from original list.

```
list l = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
list l2 = extract l, 2, 4;
printf("l:%y\nl2:%y\n", l, l2);

l:[1, 2, 7, 8, 9]
l2:[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

`select` operator supports in condition argument `$#` macro expanded as index.

```
list l = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
list l2 = select l, $# >= 2 && $# <2+4;
printf("l:%y\nl2:%y\n", l, l2);

l:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
l2:[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

The [select](https://docs.qore.org/current/lang/html/operators.html#select) operator is the best solution as you stated in your answer to your own question.

The [splice](https://docs.qore.org/current/lang/html/operators.html#splice) and [extract](https://docs.qore.org/current/lang/html/operators.html#extract) operators both will modify the list operand, which is not what you want.

Note that there is an outstanding feature issue for this in Qore ([1781](https://github.com/qorelanguage/qore/issues/1781)) - not yet targeted to a release, but it could go in the next major release (0.8.13) if there is any interest.

Comment: note that Qore 0.8.13 has been released with explicit support for list slices + the range operator etc to more easily to this; see https://docs.qore.org/qore-0.8.13/lang/html/operators.html#range_operator and https://docs.qore.org/qore-0.8.13/lang/html/operators.html#list_element_operator for more information